# Strange Array output in java

Tags: java, arrays, output

I would like to know why and how to fix this array method outputs the memory representation of `temp`.

```
public class StringMethodsExersice{
    public static int[] shiftMax(int[] num){
        int temp[] = new int[num.length];
        int firstEl = num[0];
        int lastEl = num[num.length-1];


        for(int i=1;i<num.length-1;i++){
            if(num[i] > num[i+1]){
                temp[i] = num[i];
            }
            temp[i] = num[i];
        }
        temp[0] = firstEl;
        temp[num.length-1]= lastEl;
        return temp;
    }

    public static void main (String []args){
        int[] myArray = new int [5];
        myArray [0] = 2;
        myArray [1] = 5;
        myArray [2] = 6;
        myArray [3] = 14;
        myArray [4] = 25;
        System.out.println(shiftMax(myArray));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Arrays#toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28int%5B%5D%29):

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(shiftMax(myArray)));
```

(See [its implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Arrays.java#Arrays.toString%28int%5B%5D%29) for details)

---

Explanation about the output you're getting:

Since each object has `toString()` method, the default is displaying the class name representation, then adding `@` sign and then the hashcode.

Comment: Stop stealing my answers! :P +1

Comment: Also note the existence of `Arrays.deepToString()` for embedded arrays